# Want to move value number to sit on peak of the bar chart

Tags: swiftui, bar-chart

// This creates a bar-chart showing item.totalscore by dateCreated.
// How can I put item.totalscore next to the end of the bar?

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("Prior scores")
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
          HStack{
            Text(Date2String(someDate: item.dateCreated!)).font(.caption2)
            Rectangle()
            .fill(BarChartColors(answer: item.totalscore))
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: (Double(item.totalscore)+0.5)), height: 0.7), anchor: .leading)
            Text("\(item.totalscore)").font(.caption2)
          }
        }
      }.padding()
    Spacer()
  }
```

Comment: Can u provide [a minimal representable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:
(note you will need to workout the scale)

```
@State var max = 250.0  // <-- to be determined
let maxw = 333.0 // <-- to be determined
let h = 22.0 // <-- to be determined

 var body: some View {
     VStack{
         Text("Prior scores")
         ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
           HStack{
             Text(Date2String(someDate: item.dateCreated!)).font(.caption2)
             Rectangle()
             .fill(BarChartColors(answer: item.totalscore))
             .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: Double(item.totalscore)+0.5, height: 0.7), anchor: .leading)
             .frame(width: item.totalscore / max * maxw, height: h)
             .clipped()  // <--- here

             Text("\(item.totalscore)").font(.caption2)
             Spacer()  // <--- here
           }
         }
       }.padding()
        .onAppear {
            max = items.map { Double($0.totalscore) }.max() ?? 0.0
        }
     Spacer()
   }
```